# Tokenizing strings using regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, tokenize, stringtokenizer

Suppose I've a long string containing newlines and tabs as:

```
var x = "This is a long string.\n\t This is another one on next line.";
```

So how can we split this string into tokens, using regular expression?

I don't want to use `.split(' ')` because I want to learn Javascript's Regex.

A more complicated string could be this:

```
var y = "This @is a #long $string. Alright, lets split this.";
```

Now I want to extract only the valid *words* out of this string, without special characters, and punctuation, i.e I want these:

```
var xwords = ["This", "is", "a", "long", "string", "This", "is", "another", "one", "on", "next", "line"];

var ywords = ["This", "is", "a", "long", "string", "Alright", "lets", "split", "this"];
```

Comment: What do you want to split it on? You said `s.split(' ')` but also you mentioned newlines and tabs. You seem to be looking for [a regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), which isn't really Stack Overflow's focus.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I'm reading [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) from MDN. But at the same time, I doing some experiment. And this is my first attempt to split sentence into words.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle example of what you asked: http://jsfiddle.net/ayezutov/BjXw5/1/

Basically, the code is very simple:

```
var y = "This @is a #long $string. Alright, lets split this.";
var regex = /[^\s]+/g; // This is "multiple not space characters, which should be searched not once in string"

var match = y.match(regex);
for (var i = 0; i<match.length; i++)
{
    document.write(match[i]);
    document.write('<br>');
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Basically you can expand the list of separator characters: http://jsfiddle.net/ayezutov/BjXw5/2/

```
var regex = /[^\s\.,!?]+/g;
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Only letters all the time:
http://jsfiddle.net/ayezutov/BjXw5/3/

```
var regex = /\w+/g;
```

Comment: Your both examples give wrong result. The result is containing the special characters.

Comment: Hey, i thought this was your intention :) if you wish only letters in output: http://jsfiddle.net/ayezutov/BjXw5/3/. `var regex = /\w+/g;`

Comment: +1. That is good. It seems this can be written in many different ways.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Basically, for english, `\w` is a more elegant form of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, but `\w` would work with other languages as well.

Comment: look like ```\S = ^\s```

Answer (score 2):

Use `\s+` to tokenize the string.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I did `var re = /\s+/; var words = re.exec(x);`  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Nawaz `var words = x.split(/\s+/);`

Comment: @Nawaz Also try `var words = y.split(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/);` to strip out punctuation, too.

Comment: @Kai: Of that helped for the first string. But it doesn't work with the second string `y`.

Answer (score 2):

exec can loop through the matches to remove non-word (\W) characters.

```
var A= [], str= "This @is a #long $string. Alright, let's split this.",
rx=/\W*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z']*)(\W+|$)/g, words;

while((words= rx.exec(str))!= null){
    A.push(words[1]);
}
A.join(', ')

/*  returned value: (String)
This, is, a, long, string, Alright, let's, split, this
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using regex groups to tokenise the text using different types of tokens.

You can test the code here https://jsfiddle.net/u3mvca6q/5/

```
/*
Basic Regex explanation:
/                   Regex start
(\w+)               First group, words     \w means ASCII letter with \w     + means 1 or more letters
|                   or
(,|!)               Second group, punctuation
|                   or
(\s)                Third group, white spaces
/                   Regex end
g                   "global", enables looping over the string to capture one element at a time

Regex result:
result[0] : default group : any match
result[1] : group1 : words
result[2] : group2 : punctuation , !
result[3] : group3 : whitespace
*/
var basicRegex = /(\w+)|(,|!)|(\s)/g;

/*
Advanced Regex explanation:
[a-zA-Z\u0080-\u00FF] instead of \w     Supports some Unicode letters instead of ASCII letters only. Find Unicode ranges here https://apps.timwhitlock.info/js/regex

(\.\.\.|\.|,|!|\?)                      Identify ellipsis (...) and points as separate entities

You can improve it by adding ranges for special punctuation and so on
*/
var advancedRegex = /([a-zA-Z\u0080-\u00FF]+)|(\.\.\.|\.|,|!|\?)|(\s)/g;

var basicString = "Hello, this is a random message!";
var advancedString = "Et en français ? Avec des caractères spéciaux ... With one point at the end.";

console.log("------------------");
var result = null;
do {
    result = basicRegex.exec(basicString)
    console.log(result);
} while(result != null)

console.log("------------------");
var result = null;
do {
    result = advancedRegex.exec(advancedString)
    console.log(result);
} while(result != null)

/*
Output:
Array [ "Hello",        "Hello",        undefined,  undefined ]
Array [ ",",            undefined,      ",",        undefined ]
Array [ " ",            undefined,      undefined,  " "       ]
Array [ "this",         "this",         undefined,  undefined ]
Array [ " ",            undefined,      undefined,  " "       ]
Array [ "is",           "is",           undefined,  undefined ]
Array [ " ",            undefined,      undefined,  " "       ]
Array [ "a",            "a",            undefined,  undefined ]
Array [ " ",            undefined,      undefined,  " "       ]
Array [ "random",       "random",       undefined,  undefined ]
Array [ " ",            undefined,      undefined,  " "       ]
Array [ "message",      "message",      undefined,  undefined ]
Array [ "!",            undefined,      "!",        undefined ]
null
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var words = y.split(/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract word-only characters, we use the `\w` symbol. Whether or not this will match Unicode characters or not is implementation-dependent, and you can [use this reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) to see what the case is for your language/library.

Please see Alexander Yezutov's answer (update 2) on how to apply this into an expression.