# Extract url using regex without merging

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the code below to extract the URL from a string variable named description. It works but it will merge duplicated URLs.

```
let geturl = new RegExp(/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/igm);

let urlExtracted = description.match(geturl);
```

Is there any method to change the code so that I could extract all the URLs in the order the URLs are being found in the variable even though they are duplicated?

Comment: Can you provide a list of  examples and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [tokenized match object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441915/tokenizing-strings-using-regular-expression-in-javascript) from the string and the pattern, then convert that token object into a list.

Just realized that answer I suggested uses the same code as your question. But I tried out the code you're using in [this code pen](https://codepen.io/user-name-is-taken/pen/aQzJQv) and couldn't replicate the error with this example:

```
var y = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIM-kdmKhnE  https://codepen.io/hellopravin/pen/NqLgqB  hi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441915/tokenizing-strings-using-regular-expression-in-javascript  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIM-kdmKhnE";
var regex = /(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/igm;

var match = y.match(regex);
//document.write(Array.from(match));
document.write(match);
```

Comment: You shuld show some code to make your answer better

Comment: Thanks, what is the output from your code? The URL of www.youtube.com.... only show up once right? I wanted the URLs to show up as many times as the URL is found in the text

Comment: i have just checked, seems like my string has some issues instead of the regular expression in the code. Let me check and confirm

Comment: I would like to comment that there is no issue with the codes, it is the input string issues. Thanks for the feedback and help.

Comment: No problem, If you wouldn't mind accepting my answer with the check next to my answer I'd appreciate it. @Calvin